# how force browser to download video when click tag <a> in mobile by using HTML5

Tags: html, video, download

I have video in my page, and put tag
to download video when click it, in pc is work but in mobile did not work how can make mobile download video by clicking on download button.

my code like this

```html
<div id="Video">
  <video controls autobuffer>
    <source src="f380.m4v">
    <source src="f3gp.3gp" type="video/3gp">
    <source src="fFlv.flv" type="video/flv">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <a href="f3gp.3gp" download>تحميل/download</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide specific code / html source of your use case, as your question is virtually unanswerable otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Some mobile browsers don't support this attribute: Chrome & Safari for iOS (and even safari itself) and some old android browsers. However, you can try the "Content-Disposition" header, I can't tell you if that works in that mobile browsers.

Example:

```
set the "content-disposition" header to "attachment; filename=x";
```

More about "download" attribute support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download